# How to route parameter in API Controller. Vue Js Mode History (Laravel 6)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

web.php not working

```
Route::get('api/showcart/{id}/','API\CartController@showCart');
```

app.js  when I Remove mode:'history' I Works..

```
let routes = [
    { path: '/MyCart/:id', 
    component: require('./components/MyCart.vue').default}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
                              routes,
                              mode:'history'  <------ when I remove this it works
                            })
```

Controller.php

```
public function showCart($id)
{ 
    $data = DB::table('cart')->where('user_id',$id)
            ->join('product','cart.product_id','=','product.product_id')
            ->get();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What is in your web.php file ?

Comment: Pls Check I edit it already

Comment: finally it worked! I forgot to put a '/'  into may axios.get('/api/showcart/+1)